# Angular how to display data received in BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to receive data from Api using service and pass it to components using BehaviorSubject, and then display it on screen:

This is service code:

```
    @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
    userOnChange: BehaviorSubject<User | null> = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);

    constructor(private api: HttpRequestService) {}

    getCurrentUser() {
        this.api.get<User>('/user/me', new HttpParams()).subscribe({
            next: response => {
                this.userOnChange.next(response.body);
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Component code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-topbar',
    templateUrl: './topbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./topbar.component.scss'],
})
export class TopbarComponent implements OnInit {
    public user: User | null = new User();

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router,
        public userService: UserService,
    ) {
                this.userService.userOnChange.subscribe({
            next: value => {
                if (value != null) {
                    this.user = value as User;
                    console.log(value.Username);
                    console.log(this.user.Username);
                }
            },
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }
}
```

Template Code:

```
<span *ngIf="this.user && this.user != null"> user: {{ this.user.Username }}</span>
```

Displayed value does not change on template when subject emit new user and also both console.log in subscribe block writes undefined

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the response.body. Something like this should help (not tested)

```
getCurrentUser() {
    this.api.get<User>('/user/me', new HttpParams()).subscribe({
        next: async response => {
            this.userOnChange.next(await response.body);
        },
    });
}
```

If that is not getting what you need and your value is really JSON, try .json instead.

```
getCurrentUser() {
    this.api.get<User>('/user/me', new HttpParams()).subscribe({
        next: async response => {
            this.userOnChange.next(await response.json());
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anyone calling `getCurrentUser()`, therefore nobody actually triggers http request:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-topbar',
    templateUrl: './topbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./topbar.component.scss'],
})
export class TopbarComponent implements OnInit {
    public user: User | null = new User();

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router,
        public userService: UserService,
    ) {
        this.userService.userOnChange.subscribe({
            next: value => {
                if (value != null) {
                    this.user = value as User;
                    console.log(value.Username);
                    console.log(this.user.Username);
                }
            },
        });
        this.userService.getCurrentUser(); <-- try adding this
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }
}
```

Other than that, your current implementation requires handling subscription you've got after component destroying. You can avoid it with this simplification:

```
export class TopbarComponent implements OnInit {
    public user$: BehaviorSubject<User | null>;

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService,
    ) {
        this.user$ = this.userService.userOnChange;
        this.userService.getCurrentUser();
                
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }
}
```

and a template:

```
<span *ngIf="user$ as user"> user: {{ user.Username }}</span>
```